# How can I delete Internet Browser form built-in apps?

Tags: cyanogenmod, internet, call-screening

I want to turn off completely access to www for my kid (quite smart kid :) ) and this is what I have:

1. Sony Xperia Tipo, rooted
2. Android 4.1.2. Cyanogenmod 10

What I need:
1. Ability to remove completely Internet app (not to deactivate it !!!)

My 12 yo kid knows how to use factory settings reset and unfortunately SAFEMODE access as well. I installed Applock (blocks Settings access) and Droidwall (android firewall app) but she restarted phone into SAFEMODE and removed my password protected apps (because they didn't started up in SAFEMODE) then after reboot all internet apps and settings was accessible !!!

Comment: Even if you do so it wouldn't affect her as she could get access to net

Comment: My idea would be to add applock and droidwall to `/system/priv-app` so it would be hidden and boot even in sfaemode

Comment: Probably easiest solution would be MAC address filtering on your router.

Comment: Apart from factory reset, your kid can also plug the phone in and re-flash ROM, voiding all you did before. As suggested by @Chahk, you should MAC address block the device(removing all internet access, not only web), or block ports 80, and 443 (HTTP/HTTPS)

Comment: @Chuck: I think it's bad idea... what about free public WiFi Networks and what about 3G/4G/LTE with settings accessibility? I don't want to Block all data traffic because of MMSes using Internet profile...

Comment: @TheBro21: i am pręty sure this will be her next try with FlashING ...  but for now she doesn't have enough permissions to install aby software on her Ubuntu laptop 

Comment: @user4847410: do You know how to do this with CM10? It's enough for me to have it still running and secured with password when in Safemode 

Comment: @user4847410: IT would affect her somehow - I don't want to cut her off From net completely but only want to control time spent in Internet and use of approved apps  if she is playING online game That I know that's ok but no more than one or two hours per Day and not when she is at school  now she bypasses Locked apps and Access hours entering Safemode.. Fortunately I did't install Google Apps add-on and Internet browser is not campanile with Google Play and no app she can install  she doesn't know that yet she could install everythig copying .apk file to SD Card and run locally 

Comment: @HubertBieganowski just search the net for moving apps to system

Comment: @user4847410: found al ready... /system/app Mover Root From Play Stare did all the worki 

Comment: @HubertBieganowski I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can move apps to the `/system` directory so they will not be uninstalled after a factory reset. (For example an app that locks the internet browser). However, it is still possible to install apps by using the Play Store, ADB, or root access.

Whatever you do, if you reflash the firmware, everything will be wiped and you can start over again. So the `/system` partition won't be a solution.

The only thing you can do is not tell the WiFi password, but then there are still open WiFi network.

Simply said, it is not possible.

Comment: thi scould be a solution if you could prepare special image with firewall and applock inside the /system partition and already password protected :D

Comment: It would be much easier for my kid ti buy anpther phone :D (SIM is not paired with phone....)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the internet browser from the built in apps, but if the reason behind this is to block or limit your kid from internet access, it will be pointless. Chances are, that your kid knows that you can re-flash firmware, basically wiping the System partition and re-acquiring it.

In comments, you did however mention that your kid does not have permission to install software on the Ubuntu laptop. This is not a restriction to flashing the ROM, because if one does not have root permissions, he can still install software locally, and that should be enough to flash something as far as I can tell.

A solution might be to make some sort of read-only partition, that not even root can edit, and on there, you would have a small program that counts, and limits through something like Xposed. I however doubt that the above would work and/or be practical, as you might need to make the program yourself, and I think that read-only partitions can be mounted as read-write.

Another possible solution would be to go to your router settings and limit the internet access there, however this is only a partial solution as you mentioned that you wanted to set up a counter that counts even when not at home.

---

If you have any questions regarding the router setup to achieve this goal, you can ask your question at [Super User SE](https://superuser.com/), where this would be more appropriate.